# Mysql query for three table with inner join

Tags: mysql

I need to determine which user (from the second table) was posted the image from the first table as well as whether a particular user was gave a rating of the photograph (from the third table).

The data to be passed to the php page and mysql query is

- ID of the user who opens the page
- ID of the photo that needs to be displayed

Mysql query that I've tried looks like:

```
SELECT images.*, users.name, likes.user
FROM images
INNER JOIN users
  ON users.id = images.user
LEFT JOIN likes
  ON likes.user = '22'
WHERE images.pic_name = 'pic1'
LIMIT 1
```

table images:

```
  id    |    pic_name   |    user
-------------------------------
   1    |      Pic1     |     11
   2    |      Pic2     |     22
   3    |      Pic3     |     33
```

table users:

```
   id    |     name  |  status
--------------------------------
   11    |    name 1 |    1
   22    |    name 2 |    1
   33    |    name 3 |    1
```

table likes:

```
  id   |   pic_name  | user
 ----------------------------
   1   |    pic 1    |  22
```

The result for user "22" and "Pic1" should look like:

```
   id    |    name      |    user
-----------------------------------
   1     |    name 1    |    22
```

The result for user "11" (this user is not rated picture) and "Pic1" should look like:

```
   id    |    name      |    user
-----------------------------------
   1     |    name 1    |    null
```

What mysql query would be proper and give the solution for this?

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY is a bit meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're on the right track, you're just selecting somewhat odd fields and are missing a condition in the left join that matches the picture name;

```
SELECT images.id, users.name, likes.user
FROM images
JOIN users 
  ON users.id = images.user
LEFT JOIN likes
  ON likes.pic_name = images.pic_name
 AND likes.user = 22
WHERE image.pic_name = 'pic1';
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d5a4/3).